# how to import an image in intellij IDEA?

Tags: image, intellij-idea, import

i have problem in importing images in intellij IDEA when i use this code :

```
Image  imageVariable  =  getImage( getCodeBase( ), filename );
```

it doesn't show the image when i run the program , whats the problem?

(i am sure that the file name is the same and right).

thanks

Comment: You could put the image in `resources` folder and get it from the har at runtime - please look at `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: where i can find the resources folder ? (Do you mean src folder)